# Copy all repos of an organisation to another account

Tags: github, bulk, github-organizations

I'm part of an organisation on github and would like to copy all the repos of that organisation to another regular github account at once.

I thought there would be a tool to help me to do this easily but haven't found one yet. What would be the easiest way to approach this? Thank you

I have tried looking into gh but I'm not sure it's the right tool for it. All I'm trying to do is basically cloning all the repos of the organisation I am a part of to another github account in one go

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried looking into `gh` but I'm not sure it's the right tool for it.

Considering there does not seem to be a native feature allowing for a bulk copy you want, `gh` is actually a good option.

Depending on the [fork policy of your organization](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/managing-the-forking-policy-for-your-organization) and the nature of said repositories (public or private), you should be able to write a script, using the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/), which would:

- list the repositories of an organization ([`gh repo list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_list))
- fork it ([`gh repo fork`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_fork))

Note that will not copy issues or pull-requests.